# how to open a Native Camera with FOCUS_MODE_MACRO as Default in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I opened native camera in android device as follows :

I want to open a Native Camera of the Android Device with the default setting FOCUS_MODE_MACRO. I tried and search for that but i am not getting proper solution for that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

So, anybody can help me to solve this issue. is there any parameter which i need to put in intent or is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

This camera is a bit irrelevant, but on the events of the inspection of the project have a good idea, perhaps useful for class